# C++ Operator overload calling destructor

Tags: c++, overloading, destructor, free

For my first try with operator overloading I created a vector class and tried to sum up two vectors. My class contains an array and a vector of int that both contain the same elements.

Addition works fine with the `std::vector` but I encounter two issues with the array. It seems that the destructor is called at the end of the summing operation which produces a "double free or corruption" error (core dump). Plus, the first two elements of the array are always equal to zero.

Should I also overload the `delete` or am I missing a thing ?

The header file:

```
#ifndef MYVECTOR_INCLUDE
#define MYVECTOR_INCLUDE
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

class MyVector {
public:
    MyVector(int n);
    ~MyVector();
    void set(int idx, int value);
    int get(int idx);
    void print();    
    MyVector &operator=(const MyVector &v);
    MyVector operator+(const MyVector &v);
private:
    int *data;
    std::vector<int> data_vector;
    int size1;
    int size2;
};
#endif
```

The cpp file:

```
#include "../include/myvector.hpp"

MyVector::MyVector(int n) {
    data = new int [n];
    data_vector.resize(n);
    size1 = n;
    size2 = 1;
}
MyVector::~MyVector() {
    if (data != NULL) {
        delete [] data;
    }
}
void MyVector::set(int idx, int value) {
    data_vector[idx] = value;
    data[idx] = value;
}
int MyVector::get(int idx) {
    return data_vector[idx];
}
void MyVector::print() {
    std::cout << "Vector data" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
        std::cout << data_vector[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Data" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
        std::cout << data[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
MyVector &MyVector::operator=(const MyVector &v) {
    if (this == &v)
        return *this;
    size1 = v.size1;
    size2 = v.size2;
    std::copy(v.data_vector.begin(), v.data_vector.end(), data_vector.begin());
    memcpy(&data, v.data, sizeof(int)*size1);
    return *this;
}
MyVector MyVector::operator+(const MyVector &v) {
    if ((size1 == v.size1) && (size2 == v.size2)) {
        MyVector res = MyVector(size1);
        for (int i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
            res.data_vector[i] = data_vector[i] + v.data_vector[i];
            res.data[i] = data[i] + v.data[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    else
        throw std::length_error("Vector dimensions must agree.");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Follow the Rule of 3/5/0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [the rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

The rule of three states

> If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three.

In this case, you provided the destructor and copy assignment operator but forgot the copy constructor.

In `operator+` you create a local object `MyVector res` which is later copied out and then destroyed. Since you haven't implemented a copy constructor, the default copy constructor will simply copy the original `data` pointer from `res` to another `MyVector`. When `res` is destroyed, the array pointed to by it's `data` member will be deleted, leaving the copied vector's `data` pointing to a deleted object.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't heard of this rule before.